# How does Liferay knows theme is incompatible with it?

Tags: themes, liferay, tomcat7, tomcat6, facet

I have theme that runs ok on Liferay 6.1 / Tomcat 7.

I have tried to migrate this theme to Liferay 6.1 / Tomcat 6.

The only change I made was changing web module facet to 2.5

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
```

When this theme is deployed, Liferay writes

```
17:09:33,756 ERROR [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:490] Themes in this WAR are not compatible with Liferay Portal Community Edition / 6.1.1
```

It can't react on facet record since project configuration file does not reach server on deploy.

How, how can Liferay think this theme is not his?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took a peak at `ThemeLocalServiceImpl:490` and it looks like it doesn't have anything to do with the facet but has to do with some properties.

Extract the WAR or view your code and find `liferay-plugin-package.properties`

Ensure that the property `liferay-versions` is not set or set to the version of your portal. The easiest way is to write to cover all 6.1 versions:

```
liferay-versions=6.1.0+
```

Next make sure to copy these settings over to `liferay-look-and-feel.xml` if the file exists. It should look something like this:

```
<look-and-feel>
    <compatibility>
        <version>6.1.0+</version>
    </compatibility>
    <theme id="sample-theme" name="Sample Theme">
    </theme>
</look-and-feel>
```

This should fix the issue you're having as long as you're deploying to a 6.1 portal.